# How to use transformation T from histeq in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, histogram, histogram-equalization

[The documentation of `histeq` in Matlab](https://mathworks.com/help/images/ref/histeq.html) says:

> `[___,T] = histeq(___)` also returns the transformation `T` that maps the gray component of the input grayscale image or colormap to the gray component of the output grayscale image or colormap.

How do I apply this transformation `T` to another image (not the image that I put into `histeq`)?

The input to `histeq` was a greyscale image, the output `T` is a 1×256 `double` vector.

Answer (score 0):

The following line from `histeq.m` might be the solution:

```
builtin("_grayxformmex", new_image, T);
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer